# Entity Framework Core - How to correctly map relationships with composite key?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-core

I have the following table structure

**Facility**

```
Id int (PK)
Name
```

**Visit**

```
FacilityId int 
Hour int
Value
```

Table `Visit` has the composite key `(FacilityId, Hour)`

The entity classes are defined as

```
class Facility
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }   
    public ICollection<Visit> Visits { }
}

class Visit
{
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    public int Hour { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Facility Facility { get; set; }
}
```

My `DbContext` class has the following in `OnModelCreating` method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Facility>()
                .ToTable("Facility")
                .HasKey(f => f.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Facility>()
                .HasMany(f => f.Visits)

modelBuilder.Entity<Visit>()
                .ToTable("Visits")
                .HasKey(v => new { v.FacilityId, v.Hour});
modelBuilder.Entity<Visit>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Facility)
                .WithMany(a => a.Visits)
                .HasForeignKey(a => a.FacilityId)
                .HasPrincipalKey(a => a.Id);
```

Here is the resulting JSON from my ASP.Net Core WebAPI

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Facility1","visits":null},      {"id":2,"name":"Facility2","visits":null}]
```

Question: why is the visits JSON null? What configuration am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The configuration is probably fine. What are you missing is [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

Comment: Should use `.Include` when you get `Facility`, EF have by default turn on Lazy Loading.

Comment: @IvanStoev and M. Wisnicki Thank you both for the quick response and pointing me to the documentation. I can confirm that adding the missing .Include in my controller now returns the Visits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The EF have by default turned on [Lazy Loading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/entity_framework/entity_framework_lazy_loading.htm) it's a reason why you get `"visits":null`. But it's normal. Need to use Eager loading by using the `.Include()` function on your query. See  [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data) for specific examples usage eager loading.

This sample code getall `Facility` and  `Visits`

```
 var allData =  context.Facility
               .Include(d => d.Visits)
               .ToList();
```